# Running a .bat script from PHP not working

Tags: php, cmd, system

I have an application in php which needs to call a compiler to verify if the input text was correctly written. The Compiler is in a .exe format in the server and I've created a .bat script that calls the compiler sending a text file as an input and writing the result in another text file.

If I run this .bat script from the server with the local command promt (cmd) it works perfectly and writes the output to the file.

When I call this same .bat file from PHP it just creates an empty text file. Seems as if it's not running that .exe

The .bat file is:

```
Parser < TestCode.txt > Result.txt
cat Result.txt
```

I'm calling this batch file from PHP with:
    `echo system("cmd /c Parser1.bat");`

Thanks!

Comment: do you need "cmd" when using system\exec on windows? also try the full path to the bat file

Comment: Are you using just bare file names like that (as opposed to full paths)? If so, the way the script behaves will depend on the "current working directory", which you can discover with [the `getcwd()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Comment: @Dagon `system` doesn't invoke a shell, it just runs a command, and a `.bat` file is never considered directly executable (there's no equivalent of `chmod +x` on Windows).

Comment: thanks. my windows foo is weak

Comment: @IMSoP I've tried both using the full path in the names and just bare names because I have all of the files in the same working directory. I've checked using getcwd() and the path is correct. Also I executed a dir command and I can see all of the files.